# How to set TTL in mongodb with C++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb

I want to set TTL index with C++ process in Linux.

But I've found the `ensureIndex` is removed. (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/pull/106)

The argument of `createIndex` seems only `BSONObj` can input.

I've tried:

```
mongo::DBClientConnection mConnection;
mConnection.connect("localhost");
mongo::BSONObj bObj = BSON( "mongo_date"<< 1 << "expireAfterSeconds" << 10);
mConnection.createIndex("Test.Data",bObj)
```

but the result is:

> db.system.indexes.find()

`{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "Test.Data" }`

`{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "mongo_date" : 1, "expireAfterSeconds" : 10 }, "name" : "mongo_date_1_expireAfterSeconds_10", "ns" : "Test.Data" }`

Is there something wrong or other way to set the TTL?

Thanks.

Comment: use createIndex instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I still can't find the method in C, so I use a stupid method temporarily.

I use shell script to create and run a JavaScript

In C code:

```
int expire = 321;
char expir_char[20];
sprintf(expir_char, "%d",expire);
char temp_char[30] = "./runTtlJs.sh ";
strcat(temp_char,expir_char);
system(temp_char);
```

In runTtlJs.sh:

```
echo "db.Data.dropIndex({"mongo_date":1})" > ttl.js
echo "db.Data.ensureIndex({"mongo_date":1}, { expireAfterSeconds: $1 })" >> ttl.js
mongo Test ttl.js
```

I know it's really not a good answer.